# low-quality-review guidance

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16596074) review, but can't decide the course of action. From my POV can't be fixed through editing, and none of the closure reasons seem to fit precisely:

- Not a thank-you
- Not another question
- Not having the same problem
- Not a link-only (doesn't even include a link), although is relatively spammy.

Maybe a commentary, at best. Although it is worded kinda like an answer...

Or I could choose "no comment needed", although I'm not sure how useful that is.

I know there is no shame in clicking *skip*, but I'd like to get a better idea on how to proceed with this kind of reviews.

Comment: This answer has been deleted, so it's an audit and a rather bad one. I personally would prefer to delete it, but the SO guide line would expect a "looks ok" from us, since it tries to answer the question and the poster writes, that he is involved with the tool he's promoting here (i.e. no spam).

Comment: imho it's a link-only answer without a link. It's just a tool advertisement and if you want to use it you have to google it first. So it's a VLQ answer (ignoring the fact that it has been spam-nuked).

Comment: Well, at least I didn't fail the audit. :) Still, it doesn't look like a genuine attempt to answer the question, IMO. But I guess I understand the rationale.

Comment: @Tom, it was an audit, but the expected action wasn't "Looks ok" but recommending deletion. I guess that _you_ wouldn't have passed this audit... ;)

Comment: You should guess less ;P.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is spam. Alternatively, assuming you take "Our tool, the Simplement Liberator" as disclosure (it is), it's not an answer. This answer doesn't explain how to use the tool, it simply advertises the tool and says it solves the problem.

The correct option is to delete this "answer".

Answers are allowed to recommend a tool, but it is expected they explain how to utilize the tool to solve the question that was asked.

In this case, I'd select to delete it an utilize "No comment". The other option that makes the most sense is the "link only" option.

Comment: Yup, but "spam" is not a one of the closure reasons offered. Should I shoose "no comment needed", and expect that be enough? Since it's an audit, I guess it's not really important for this question on itself...

Comment: For me, the take-away is: "choose no-comment-necessary when rejecting spam".